# Can I use the .NET Framework from JavaScript (JScript) or VBScript?

Tags: .net, javascript, windows, scripting, vbscript

I want to write a script that can run on a vanilla Windows (XP or later) system and call methods in an installed (GAC'd) .NET assembly.  (I need to deliver the script to other people and I don't want to assume that they have anything in particular installed (other than the the assembly in question).  Can I use JavaScript (JScript) or VBScript (in conjunction with the standard Windows *cscript*/*wscript* commands) to do this somehow?

Comment: Does it have to be a script?  If there's an installed .net assembly, you could safely assume the framework is installed and provide a small console app.

Answer (score 3):

If the class whose methods you wish to call is exposed to COM, you should be able to do something like this (VBScript):

```
Dim o
Set o = CreateObject("MyAssembly.MyObject")
o.MyMethod()
```

ScottS' answer has a good link.

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried it, but I would think your best bet would be to call the .Net component via COM interop.  This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973802.aspx) should get you started.